# Omit curly braces for for-statement / if-statement will cause performance issue?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
Stopwatch t1 = new Stopwatch();

t1.Start();
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 2000000001; j++)
     i += 1;
t1.Stop();



Stopwatch t2 = new Stopwatch();

t2.Start();
int k = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 2000000001; j++)
{
     k += 1;
}
t2.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(t1.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine(t2.Elapsed);

Console.ReadLine();
```

O/P:

```
00:00:05.0266990

00:00:04.7179756
```

**performance depends on variable name also?**

Comment: How many times did you run this?

Comment: Is that statistically significant? i.e. did you run a number of times and compute mean and standard error of the mean? Also, try swapping the loops round.

Comment: no, basically; that shouldn't cause a problem at all. Most likely you're either seeing JIT/fusion time, or just plain old randomness

Comment: Take a look at the produced IL with ILSPY, I don't believe there will be a difference. If you benchmark, do not benchmark two different things in one instance. Benchmark them in two separated runs.

Comment: Or maybe variables named `k` are faster than variables named `i`?

Comment: Not too much difference on me. `04.3348718` and `04.2906805`.

Comment: You should only be worrying about the performance of this if it is the last thing you have to be working on, even then I'd reconsider. Note: My results `00:00:04.2359030` and `00:00:04.2384355`

Comment: @Default The code with brackets already is faster (I think you mean 'slower')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, omitting curly braces will not have any effect on the performance. The difference you are seeing is probably due to program warming up in the start. Swap those two code block and you will see the same difference or none.

If you build your program in release mode and open the executable in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) *(ILSpy version 2.1.0.1603)* then you will see that curly braces has been added. :

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();
    t.Start();
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2000000001; j++)
    {
        i++;
    }
    t.Stop();
    Stopwatch t2 = new Stopwatch();
    t2.Start();
    int k = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < 2000000001; l++)
    {
        k++;
    }
    t2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(t.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine(t2.Elapsed);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Original code:

```
Stopwatch t1 = new Stopwatch();
t1.Start();
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 2000000001; j++)
    i += 1;
t1.Stop();
Stopwatch t2 = new Stopwatch();

t2.Start();
int k = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 2000000001; j++)
{
    k += 1;
}
t2.Stop();
```

Comment: actually, swapping the code blocks (in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)) the bracket block is still executed faster. Not sure what configuration they run under though. Changing the second `j` to `p` will however change that. It seems the IL code will be different when using a new for parameter name (there is an extra `int32 V_5` generated when for parameter name is different).

Comment: @Default, dotnetfiddle seems like a good resource, I wasn't aware of it. Thanks, and yes I believe even if there is going to be a performance difference then it would negligible. It is just a random difference that we are seeing. Braces has nothing to do with it.

Comment: no, you are correct about brackets. but it does seem to have to do with the variable name. note that `j` is reused in the for loops. it generates different ILs (dotnetfiddle can show that too). Still negligible though :)